# Centrar texto verticalmente en una tabla en latex

Tags: latex

Hola tengo el siguiente problema

Estoy realizando una tabla en látex y me quiero centrar el texto de la primer columna de la tabla de manera vertical.

Adjunto el codigo

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tabular} {|c| p{15cm} |}        
    \hline
    \multirow {3}{3cm}{\textbf{Estado actual}} & El historial clínico de los pacientes se completa de forma manual. \\ \cline{2-2}
    & El control de los ingresos y egresos proveniente de la facturación se realizan en distintas planillas de cálculos. \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Oportunidad} & Mejorar el proceso de consulta, búsqueda y almacenamiento de la información vinculada a los pacientes y al control de la facturación evitando el uso del papel. \\
    \hline 
    \multirow  {3}{3cm}{\textbf{Cambios y mejoras}} & Agilización en la entrega y programación de turnos. \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Mejora en la metodología de trabajo. \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Centralización de la información, fundamental para el desarrollo de diagnósticos y/o controles médicos. \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Logros} & Implementar un sistema de gestión. \\   
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Análisis, oportunidad, cambios y mejoras.}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios problemas mezclados en la tabla que intentas hacer:

- El especificador `c` centra horizontalmente, pero no verticalmente. Esto podría corregirse usando el paquete `array` y el especificador de columna `m{ancho}` que sí lograría centrar verticalmente, o el especificador `w{c}{ancho}`, que centraría verticalmente y también horizontalmente la celda, en una caja de ancho dado.
- Pero ese centrado vertical no funciona en las celdas que usen `\multirow`.
- Además las celdas que usan `\multirow` crean su propia caja de texto dentro de la cual hay una justificación local (a la izquierda) independientemente de que en la cabecera de la columna hayas puesto `c`. Esto puede arreglarse añadiendo el comando `\centering` al contenido de esa celda multirow.
- Pero el centrado vertical de una celda multirow no es posible automáticamente. Puede lograrse sin embargo usando un parámetro opcional de multirow que iría entre corchetes así: `\multirow{}{}[correccion]{}`. En ese parámetro se puede especificar una distancia (positiva o negativa) para desplazar el contenido de esa celda verticalmente. Así pueden probarse valores hasta que quede alineada a tu gusto.

Combinando todo lo anterior, mi solución usa:

- Paquete `array` y tipos de celda `w` para la primera columna y `m` para la segunda (gracias a esto todas las celdas que no son multirow salen correctamente centradas verticalmente)
- Corrección en cada comando `multirow` para alinear verticalmente estas celdas.
- Comando `\centering` dentro de cada celda `multirow` para alinearlas también horizontalmente.

Todo junto:

```
    \begin{tabular} {|w{c}{3cm}| m{15cm} |}        
    \hline
    \multirow {2}{3cm}[-.6em]{\centering\textbf{Estado actual}} & El historial clínico de los pacientes se completa de forma manual. \\ \cline{2-2}
    & El control de los ingresos y egresos proveniente de la facturación se realizan en distintas planillas de cálculos. \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Oportunidad} & Mejorar el proceso de consulta, búsqueda y almacenamiento de la información vinculada a los pacientes y al control de la facturación evitando el uso del papel. \\
    \hline 
    \multirow  {3}{3cm}[-.6em]{\centering\textbf{Cambios y mejoras}} & Agilización en la entrega y programación de turnos. \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Mejora en la metodología de trabajo. \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Centralización de la información, fundamental para el desarrollo de diagnósticos y/o controles médicos. \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Logros} & Implementar un sistema de gestión. \\   
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Otra opción

Si me lo permites, creo que la tabla que estabas intentando hacer no es muy bonita. Sé que esto puede ser cuestión de gustos, pero en todos los libros sobre tipografía que he leido siempre he visto desaconsejado el uso de líneas horizontales en las tablas, y prácticamente prohibido el uso de líneas verticales. Hay un paquete llamado `booktabs` cuya documentación puedes leer para ver ejemplos de tablas usando las típicas rejillas de líneas horizontales y verticales, junto con otras posiblidades más agradables tipográficamente.

Usando ese paquete y modificando tu tabla, es posible eliminar todos los problemas de centrado que tenías (simplemente evitando el uso de multicol y cambiando la alineación de la primera columna a la derecha) y a la vez conseguir una tabla que en mi opinión se ve más bonita (eliminando las líneas verticales y reduciendo el uso de horizontales).

Este sería el código:

```
    \begin{tabular} {r p{12cm}}        
    \toprule
    \textbf{Estado actual}     & El historial clínico de los pacientes se completa de forma manual. \\
                               & El control de los ingresos y egresos proveniente de la facturación se 
                                 realizan en distintas planillas de cálculos. \\
                               \cmidrule{2-2}
    \textbf{Oportunidad}       & Mejorar el proceso de consulta, búsqueda y almacenamiento de la información
                                 vinculada a los pacientes y al control de la facturación evitando el uso del papel. \\
                               \cmidrule{2-2}
    \textbf{Cambios y mejoras} & Agilización en la entrega y programación de turnos. \\ 
                               & Mejora en la metodología de trabajo. \\
                               & Centralización de la información, fundamental para el desarrollo de diagnósticos
                                 y/o controles médicos. \\ 
                               \cmidrule{2-2}
    \textbf{Logros}            & Implementar un sistema de gestión. \\   
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

Y se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]